# group by 3 columns and max of 1 column, and show the values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such

```
       timestamp                    Format  MachineMode  \
0      2022-08-04 07:49:00+00:00    2000          3.0   
1      2022-08-04 07:50:00+00:00    2000          3.0   
2      2022-08-04 07:51:00+00:00    2000          3.0   
3      2022-08-04 07:52:00+00:00    2000          3.0   
4      2022-08-04 07:53:00+00:00    2000          3.0   
...                          ...     ...          ...   
59825  2022-12-07 06:43:00+00:00    2000          1.0   
59826  2022-12-07 06:44:00+00:00    2000          1.0   
59827  2022-12-07 06:45:00+00:00    2000          1.0   
59828  2022-12-07 06:49:00+00:00    2000          1.0   
59829  2022-12-07 06:50:00+00:00    2000          1.0   

                        RecipeName  ProductionSpeed  TankPressure  \
0                       2 LT Fanta       500.001283          4.72   
1                       2 LT Fanta       500.001650          4.71   
2                       2 LT Fanta       500.001333          4.72   
3                       2 LT Fanta       500.001350          4.71   
4                       2 LT Fanta       308.336100          5.37   
...                            ...              ...           ...   
59825  2 LT Coca Cola_23K Duo Pack       383.335217          4.80   
59826  2 LT Coca Cola_23K Duo Pack       383.335000          4.81   
59827  2 LT Coca Cola_23K Duo Pack       306.667767          4.82   
59828  2 LT Coca Cola_23K Duo Pack       364.168333          4.53   
59829  2 LT Coca Cola_23K Duo Pack       325.833783          4.76   

       CarouselPressure  
0                  0.98  
1                  0.98  
2                  0.98  
3                  0.98  
4                  0.96  
...                 ...  
59825              1.01  
59826              0.98  
59827              0.99  
59828              0.93  
59829              0.99
```

I want to resample the data to an hourly level, groupby the Format, Machinemode, recipename and the MAX productionspeed for that hour and display the TankPressure, CarouselPressure when the productionspeed is highest for that hour.

I have tried

```
new_bg1=new_bg.groupby(['RecipeName','Format','MachineMode', pd.Grouper(freq='H')]).ProductionSpeed.agg(['max','idxmax']).reset_index()
```

but I can't get it to show the values for the tankpressure and carouselpressure.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `new_bg.loc[new_bg.groupby(['RecipeName','Format','MachineMode', pd.Grouper(freq='H')])['ProductionSpeed'].idxmax()]`

Comment: but I want it to show me the values for the carousel pressure and tankpressure as well.

Comment: This will do that. Please provide a smaller example (well formatted as DataFrame constructor, or at least without the table broken in different parts) and the matching expected output

Comment: yes this works thank you, but this doesnt produce the "resampled" timestamp, basically a column on timestamps at an hourly level. I would like to have that, anyway I can get that?

Comment: Maybe first `assign` as a new column then use that to `groupby`